# Javascript: Checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one page I have two form for search:

```
<form class="search-panel" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return searchRedirect(this)">
        <input type="test" name="searchFor" />
        <div class="additional-search-button"></div>
        <div id="additional-search-box">
            <div class="as-cont">
                Books<input type="radio" name="category" value="Books" checked="1" /><br/>
                School<input type="radio" name="category" value="School" /><br/>
                Music<input type="radio" name="category" value="Music" />
            </div>
        </div>
       <input type="submit" name="search" />
    </form>

<form class="search-panel" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return searchRedirect(this)">
            <input type="test" name="searchFor" />
            Games<input type="radio" name="category" value="Games" checked="1" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" />
        </form>
```

My problem is that if I click search for Games in searchRedirect always alert Books, School or Music if they checked:

That is my javascript function:

```
function searchRedirect(form) {
    alert($(form['category']+':checked').val());

    if($(form['category']+':checked').val() == 'Форум')
        window.location.href = '/forum/search.php?keywords='+form['searchFor'].value;
    else {
        window.location.href = '/Search/'+$(form['category']+':checked').val()+'/'+form['searchFor'].value;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I need if I click to search games - search only for games, if click to search books,school or music - searching only for them. But now search form for games always use first form checked buttons.

Comment: Just for your information, there are more semantic elements that you can use in forms (rather than div). `<label>` for labeling form controls (`<input>`s), and `<fieldset>` + `<legend>` to group related form controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form['category']` will give you a `NodeList` of all form elements whose name is `category`, thus you can't use it as a selector by concatenating it with `:checked`. It'd be the equivalent of `$("[object NodeList]:checked")`.

Since you are already using jQuery, you can use the following instead:

```
alert($(form).find("input[name='category']:checked").val());
```

That is, within the context of `form`, find every `input` element with name `category` that is `checked`, and get its `value`.

Comment: @Defense, if it fixed your problem why not to up vote the answer?

Comment: @Defense, yes, but as for me it would be honest to click on the up arrow (right above the digit). The answer is really good.

Answer (score 1):

you can't real do `form["category"] + ":checked"`, instead use jQuery's filter method and than use 'this' to reference the form. Also, you can/should use jQuery .submit() to catch the event instead of an inline handler and just for clearer code (and also for better performance) put the `$(form['category']+':checked')` into a variable so jquery won't need to search for the element again and again.
This is a sample:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
var checked = $(this['category']).filter(':checked');
var value = checked.val();
alert(value);
})​
```

This is a fiddle so you can fiddle (the e passed to the submit callback is the event object and e.preventDefault is like returning false so the form won't submit):
http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7Vd/

Comment: F@#K, I had the window open for a while, came back and didn't refresh before writing the answer...I was sure they had AJAXed this to get new posts without refresh...well, there's another answer...Anyway, I suggest using .submit and variables...